# Protecting an ASP.Net Core WebApi using individual account and AzureAd account

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, blazor

I have a requirement to secure an Asp.net core Web Api Application using ASP.NET Core Identity platform.
So users can login to the application using a individual account which is stored in the database.

The authorization logic and access control logic will be handled using the local user information.

Also the requirement to link the above mentioned individual account with an AzureAd account to give single sign on experience for the end users. Username or email(UPN) can be paired for this purpose.

**Goal:**
Users should be able to log-in to a Blazor Client SPA application where they have two options to login either using

1. A Username & Password (Individual Account)
2. An AzureAd account (SSO)

I can see there are lot of resources which explains both mechanism but I couldn't find any hybrid solution.

A real world example:
You can use your email and password or a Google account to log in to the StackOverflow site.

How can I achieve this? Is there any technical term to explain the scenario?
I'm looking for some tutorial and some examples.

Comment: Can you receive the scheme that add a link to direct to the sign in page of azure ad (that means you provide 2 login page, one is your custom sign in page another is microsoft login page), this will have the least affect to your program.

Comment: @Tiny-wa Yes, that is my idea. There will be two different pages for each type of login. The same user needs (Individual) to be authenticated regardless of which page is used for login (Like in stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks for reply, and in this scenario, let's say your login page need to add a new button 'sign with azure ad', and after clicking it, the browser jump to the sign in page from microsoft, after sign in successfully, it will redirect to the home page of your program. Here I think you need to show the user name in the header of the view. And it's an important point here, whether you need to show the `Individual Account` user name rather than the azure ad account? If you need it, I think a user mapping in your database is necessary, e.g. userid and azure ad account in one row in a table.

Comment: And I think you may refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph), in this sample, it offers a sign in button which will redirect to login page after clicking.

Comment: @Tiny-wa Always I need to show the Individual Account username in the page. Not only displaying the name, but all security check like role based authentication  should be done internally. The external provide is just for login. So my question is how to do the user mappings right way?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's suitable for your schema, maybe you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/tutorial-bulk-invite), it shows how to bulk invite guests into azure ad tenant, so that the user's email address can used to sign in azure ad.